# Searching a string for any permutation of words

Tags: javascript, algorithm, strings, combinatorics, time-limit-exceeded

> Given a string and an array of words, return all indexes in string for which a concatenation of all words in the array,
>   in any order (so ["eensie", "weensy", "spider"] has six orderings) can be matched. All words will be the same length.

I am new to programming so please tell me where my big slow down points are. I still am failing the time test.

```
 var findSubstring = function(s, words) {
         var concatLength = 
         for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++){
         concatLength += words[i].length;
       } //concatLength is now length of all possible concatentations
       var stringLength = s.length;
       var answers = [];

       if (concatLength > stringLength || concatLength === 0){
           return answers;
       }  //outlier cases where answer is inevitably an empty array
         var wordLength = words[0].length  //each word is the same length          
         var currentPerm;  //this will be used in permutation function we call
       for (var i = 0; i < stringLength + 1 - concatLength; i++){ 
           try { //if a match is found in recursive permutations function, an object of type TrueValue is thrown up the stack
             wordsInString(words.slice(), -1, s.substr(i, concatLength));
           }
           catch(e){
               if (e.constructor === TrueValue)
                   answers.push(i);
               else
                  throw e;
           }

       }
       function TrueValue() { //constructor of instances to be thrown up stack in case of match
       }
       function wordsInString(words, index, string){ //permutations function
         if (index === -1)  //In each loop outside it is called with -1 as index, so we reset currentPerm to be empty
                    currentPerm = [];  
         if (words.length === 0){  //if currentPerm is full, check if it matches string.  If so throw instance of TrueValue up the stack
                   if (currentPerm.join("") === string)
                       throw new TrueValue();
               }
          for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++){
            if (string.substr(0,(currentPerm.length + 1) * wordLength) === currentPerm.join("") + words[i]){ //if what is already in currentPerm were to have this word concatenated onto it, would it be potential match of index of string we are currently on?  If so, move this word off of words array and onto currentPerm.  Continue to try all possible concatenations of words we have left via recursion
                     currentPerm.push(String(words.splice(i, 1)));
                     wordsInString(words, i, string);
                   }
               }
               if (index !== -1) //unless this is the first call to wordsInCurrentString, take last word of currentPerm off and move it back onto the place it was on in words before this particular call was made
                   words.splice(index, 0, currentPerm.pop());
               else 
                   return false;
           }
       return answers;
    };
```

Comment: Can you give a few examples of inputs **and outputs**? I'm not very clear on the description.

Comment: What bounds are you given on the lengths of the strings and the number of strings?

Answer (score 2):

OK, first of all, exceptions are slow. Any code that uses exceptions in the normal flow of the application will be slow. Only use exceptions for something that has gone terribly wrong in your application, never for the normal execution of your code.

Having said that, I approached the problem from a different angle. You have two tasks in essence: the first task is to generate all the permutations of the input array of words. The second task is, for every permutation of the words you calculate, concatenate them into a pattern string, and try to find that pattern in your input string wherever it may occur. Since these are two entirely separate tasks, isolate them in separate functions. The great thing about doing this is that you can test them separately and only use them in the overall solution when you know they work properly.

The second task is actually way simpler than the code you have, where you are continually chopping up the input string through `substr()`. You are missing the `indexOf()` function which just returns the index of the pattern in the string, or -1 if it was not found. Even better, the second parameter to `indexOf()` is the starting index for the search (with a default of 0).

Here's one way of doing that second task.

```
var findPermutation = function (permutation, s, result) {
  "use strict";
  var i, index,  
      pattern = permutation.join("");

  for (i = 0; i < s.length - pattern.length; i += 1) {
    index = s.indexOf(pattern, i);
    if (index >= 0) {
      result.push(index);
      i = index;
    }
  }
};

var result = [];
findPermutation(['a', 'b', 'c'], "abcabc", result);
console.log(result); // should be [0, 3]
findPermutation(['c', 'a', 'b'], "abcabc", result);
console.log(result); // should now be [0, 3, 2]
```

A few things to note here: `permutation` is some permutation of an array of words and so is itself an array. `s` is the string to search through, and `result` is an array of indexes that have been found. The `for` loop is cut short when the remaining bit of the string to search through is smaller than the pattern length. The code at the end is testing this simple routine (and if I'd written it properly, the test code would itself check that `result` has the right values. So, *BOOM*, we have the second part done; now all we have to do is generate the complete set of permutations from an array.

Here, I did it in a functional style: rather than have the routine generate, say, a huge array of all the permutations, I wrote the routine to accept a callback function and this will be called for every permutation that was generated (after which the permutation can be thrown away). In other words, the permutation generator would generate the next permutation, execute the callback function with this value, and then go back and calculate the next permutation. It would stop this merry-go-round once all the permutations had been generated.

For the permutation generator I went with Heap's Algorithm. It's the fastest, you can [read up about it on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap's_algorithm), and I'd already written about the algorithm and written [a JavaScript version on my blog](http://jmbk.nl/i6K2D). Here's that code:

```
var generatePermutations = function (items, process) {
  "use strict";
  var generate = function (last, items, process) {
    var
      i,
      swap = function (x, y) {
        //console.log(x + " <=> " + y);
        var temp = items[x];
        items[x] = items[y];
        items[y] = temp;
      };

    //console.log(last);
    if (last === 0) {
      process(items);
    }
    else {
      // if last is even
      if ((last & 1) !== 1) { 
        for (i = 0; i < last; i += 1) {
          generate(last - 1, items, process);
          swap(0, last);
        }
      }
      // else last is odd
      else {
        for (i = 0; i < last; i += 1) {
          generate(last - 1, items, process);
          swap(i, last);
        }
      }
      generate(last - 1, items, process);
    }
  };

  generate(items.length - 1, items, process);
};

generatePermutations(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], function (items) {
  console.log(items.join(""));
});
```

The last bit of the code shows how it is called: an array of items to be permuted and then a callback function that will be called for every permutation generated (all this one does is to merely output the items joined into a string).

If you are not familiar with this style of writing callback functions you can separate them out like this:

```
var callbackFunction = function (items) {
  console.log(items.join(""));
};
generatePermutations(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], callbackFunction);
```

So now we have it all: a permutation-of-words generator and a pattern matcher for each permutation of words. Since the callback function is so simple -- it only requires one parameter, yet the matcher requires three, I wrapped things up in another function:

```
var findPermutations = function (s, words) {
  "use strict";
  var result = [];

  generatePermutations(words, function (permutation) {
    var i, index,  
        pattern = permutation.join("");

    for (i = 0; i < s.length - pattern.length; i += 1) {
      index = s.indexOf(pattern, i);
      if (index >= 0) {
        result.push(index);
        i = index;
      }
    }
  });

  return result;
};

console.log(findPermutations("abcdabcd", ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']));
```

Again I threw in a small test case at the end to check that everything worked. If you run it, it'll output `[0, 4, 3, 2, 1]` (with the matching patterns being `abcd`, `abcd`, `dabc`, `cdab`, `bcda`).

Aside: things that still aren't great.

1. The permutation generator is a bit long-winded and can be rewritten to use some helper functions.
2. The permutation generator modifies the input array of words. It should make a copy, so that the original array is not changed.
3. I ignored the case where the length of the concatenated words is longer than the search string and hence nothing needs to be done. Easy exercise for the reader.

Comment: Generating permutations then attempting to match each one will be crazy slow. Suppose he has ten words to match. That is over 3MM permutations. The problem is not to generate permutations but to recognize them.

Comment: An excellent point, and one that actually makes sense of the requirement of each word in the array being exactly the same length (which I originally found a peculiar restriction). So now it would be:enumerate all substrings of length equal to the length of the concatenated words, and then split each substring into equal length "words" and see if they are present in the array. Except... you'd have to take care of repeated "words".

Answer (score 1):

### Error

The second line should probably be `var concatLength = 0;`.  I assume you omitted the `= 0` accidentally when posting.

### Readability

Your code was not that easy to read and analyze.  Factors hindering readability include inconsistent indentation, occasional omission of braces, verbose comments, and long lines.

In particular, you're probably better off not writing this monster line.  The code itself is already quite wide; appending a whole paragraph to it is pointless noise.  If you must write a long comment, make it a block that is limited to a reasonable width.  Better yet, try to write code that doesn't require such lengthy explanations.

> ```
>             if (string.substr(0,(currentPerm.length + 1) * wordLength) === currentPerm.join("") + words[i]){ //if what is already in currentPerm were to have this word concatenated onto it, would it be potential match of index of string we are currently on?  If so, move this word off of words array and onto currentPerm.  Continue to try all possible concatenations of words we have left via recursion
> ```

### Recursion

`wordsInString()` is a weird recursive helper function.  It can either return `false`, return an array, or throw a `new TrueValue()` object.  In any case, its return value is always ignored.  Basically, the exception is just a horrible hack to unwind the call stack.  A reasonable recursive function should return meaningful results.

### Algorithm

I can't think of an approach that is much better than brute force.  That said, there are smart and dumb brute-force implementations.

Generating all possible permutations of words beforehand would be a ridiculous proposition, since permutations grow as O(*n*!).  I'm glad you didn't do that.

The reasonable approach would be to see which word occurs first, then check whether the suffix contains the rest of the words.  That's basically your strategy.  However, you're doing it using calls to `string.substr(…)` and `currentPerm.join("")`, which involve a lot of memory allocation and copying.  What you want to use instead is `string.startsWith()`.  And when you find a word that matches, you don't have to keep verifying that match again in the future.

### Suggested solution

```
function indexesOfWords(words, s) {
    'use strict';

    // Tests whether every word appears in s, starting at index i,
    // consecutively in any order.
    function isEveryWordAt(words, s, i) {
        for (var w = 0; w < words.length; w++) {
            if (s.startsWith(words[w], i)) {
                // Found a word; look for all remaining words
                return isEveryWordAt(
                    words.slice(0, w).concat(words.slice(w + 1)),
                    s,
                    i + words[w].length
                );
            }
        }
        return words.length == 0;
    }

    // Assume all words are the same length, as promised
    var wordsLen = words.length ? words.length * words[0].length : 0;

    var startingIndexes = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < s.length - wordsLen; i++) {
        if (isEveryWordAt(words, s, i)) {
            startingIndexes.push(i);
        }
    }
    return startingIndexes;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no link to the original problem description and so it is difficult to judge how tight the solution has to be algorithmically in order to meet the requirements.

200_success has already done an excellent job on the algorithmics. Should the performance of that solution not be enough (competition, coding challenge above beginner level) then there are several improvements that can be applied.

The approach chosen by 200_success divides the problem into two distinct subproblems:

- find a possible starting location - i.e., an occurrence of *any* of the words
- for each such candidate location, see if the tail contains the rest of the words in any order

The first part can be sped up by employing any of the usual search algorithms that are capable of handling multiple search patterns simultaneously, like the [Knuth-Morris-Pratt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm) or [Boyer-Moore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string_search_algorithm). If there's no implementation of those at hand, performance can still be improved with a few heuristics inspired by these algorithms. Also, there are other algorithms - like [Shift-And](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitap_algorithm) a.k.a. bitap - that can deliver decent speed but are easier to implement.

The second part - matching the list of words at the candidate location - is most succinctly formulated in recursive form, as 200_success did: we declare a match if the word at the current location is in the list of words and its tail matches the list of words minus the current word.

A possible improvement here is to track the current state explicitly - for example in the form of a bitmap - instead of rewriting the list of words physically.

For small numbers of words (up to 64) this bitmap can be held in a machine word or integer variable. The zero-based word list index of the word at the current location can thus easily be checked; if that bit in the state bitmap is not yet set then we set it and continue matching the rest. If it is set already then we have a sequence error (two occurrences of the same word). At this point the whole match procedure needs to be reset and restarted at the position after the first occurrence of this word in the current working window.

Of course, there's no need to actually do all the work again, since it can be simulated by manipulating the bitmap and working position. At least that's the basic idea. The devil is in the details; before this optimisation can applied the list of words needs to be checked regarding the consequences of shifted self-overlap. Otherwise the safe route should be chosen, which is to restart the matching procedure at the character right after the current start position.

Efficient matching of words against the list can be arranged in any number of ways; the easiest would be the use of a hash map (so that each of the w words can be associated with an index in the range 0 to w-1). An efficiently implemented word matching logic can be a good approximation for a full-scale optimised search algorithm like KMP for finding candidate locations; it all depends on the runtime requirements which were not specified.